# pip install django-mongodb-engine Error: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, django, mongodb, installation, django-mongodb-engine

i hope someone here can help me cause iam really struggling with this for about 12 hours+.

I try to use Django with MongoDb Using the following Instruction for the packages http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/

which want me to install

1. `pip install ***ps://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-nonrel/get/tip.tar.gz`
2. `pip install ***ps://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangotoolbox/get/tip.tar.gz`
3. `pip install ***ps://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/tarball/master`

I managed the first 2, however I get the following errors when I try to install the mongodb-engine. 
I tried various forms to install it like "`pip install django-mongodb-engine`"

### I get the following error:

> "C:\Users\Burnie\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install django-mongodb-engine
>   Collecting django-mongodb-engine
>     Using cached django-mongodb-engine-0.6.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 20, in 
>         File "C:\Users\Burnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ntl4z4sp\django-mongodb-engine\setup.py", line 3, in 
>           import django_mongodb_engine as distmeta
>         File "C:\Users\Burnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ntl4z4sp\django-mongodb-engine\django_mongodb_engine__init__.py", line 12,
>    in 
>           from django.conf import settings
>         File "C:\Users\Burnie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py", line 88
>           except ImportError, e:
>                             ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Burnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ntl4z4sp\django-mongodb-
>   engine"

MySystem:
Windows 7,
Anaconda (as python distribution) 64bit

I hope someone can help me on that.

Comment: What Python version are you using? This looks like you're using some Python 3 version but the code is Python 2.7 still.

Comment: Yeah i am using python 3.4. I am not sure right now but i think i also tried it with python 2.7, i tried a lot the last days. But i will try it with 2.7 tomorrow again.

Comment: It works with python 2.7.10 thank you very very very MUCH!!!!!
However is there any possibility to get it running with 3.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitbucket versions of the code are pretty old now. You should use the ones on [github](http://github.com/django-nonrel) instead.

```
pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/django/tarball/master
pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/tarball/master
pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/tarball/master
```

There's also some more up to date instructions on getting this working available in the [mongodb-engine documentation](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html)